# It is possible to slow down time without a Black Hole?

Tags: science-based, hard-science, time, time-manipulation

Well, I saw a interesting question in other sites and it made me wondering.

Since cryogenics and hibernation aren't exactly that easy, and colony ships that travel through the eons in space carrying generation and generation of people, it wouldn't be "easier" to slow down time just for you?
This way you could travel thousands of years, but only feel like it was a few hours.

Well, a slow-mo machine is way more complicated than a space colony, hibernation and cryogenics.
**But I wonder what it would be necessary to make it work.**

Well, I know that when you accelerate to relativistics speeds, this phenomenon also happens. But let's keep it aside from now.

Comment: Pick one between science based and hard science. They cannot coexist

Comment: Please clarify what you don't want: large masses (as in the title) or high speed (like in the body)?

Comment: Whilst I’m certain that singularities are not your only option for relative time difference I’m sure it’s the only practical one.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think it's possible.

Time dilation requires energy. There's two ways to do it: travel closer to the speed of light or use a mass to distort the local space-time (or a combination).

So instead I'll try to give you an alternative: build the people you want in the last section of the trip.

We have been 3D printing bodyparts for a few years now. If you assume we can build every complex organ by the time you can send generation ships, you could reduce the resources required to use the ship at all.

The first few thousand years the ship is "empty". The crew is a sterile biological paste stored somewhere. There is no energy required for lifesupport, no food, no air, no water, no lights, no heat (or cold), no radiation protection, no need to build clothing etc. When the ship reaches it's final few years it'll start 3D printing bodies and putting them through a training program while the lifesupport finally has to do its work. By the time the ship is in orbit/landed at it's destination the crew has been alive for long enough to know it's tasks. It wont be the couple of hours you want, but it wont be the thousands of years that multiple generations wouls need to go through either and at a fraction of the lifesupport costs.

Comment: This is a frame challenge, and should be labelled as such.